# Sterling database silverlight ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: silverlight, exception, sterling-db

We are developing an out-of-browser application using sterling and we have the following scenario:

1. The app can be opened with a shortcut
2. If we open-edit files (with specific extension) the app opens up.

Problem is that instances opened in case 2 seems to have a different IsolatedStorage and data is not being shared, so we tried to do the following

```
 var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\MyApp\\";
 IsolatedStorageDriver driver = new IsolatedStorageDriver(folder,true);
        driver.DatabaseName = "sterling";
        Database = _engine.SterlingDatabase.RegisterDatabase<OurInternalDB>(driver);
```

This produces the following exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: basePath
>     StackTrace:
>          at Wintellect.Sterling.IsolatedStorage.PathProvider._ContractForBasePath(String basePath)
>          at Wintellect.Sterling.IsolatedStorage.PathProvider.GetKeysPath(String basePath, String databaseName, Type tableType, ISterlingDriver driver)
>          at Wintellect.Sterling.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageDriver.DeserializeKeys(Type type, Type keyType, IDictionary dictionary)
>          at Wintellect.Sterling.Keys.KeyCollection`2._DeserializeKeys()
>          at Wintellect.Sterling.Keys.KeyCollection`2..ctor(ISterlingDriver driver, Func`2 resolver)
>          at Wintellect.Sterling.Database.TableDefinition`2..ctor(ISterlingDriver driver, Func`2 resolver, Func`2 key)
>          at Wintellect.Sterling.Database.BaseDatabaseInstance.CreateTableDefinition[T,TKey](Func`2 keyFunction)
>          at Waf.Dal.Sterling.Database.OURInternalDB.RegisterTables()
>          at Wintellect.Sterling.Database.BaseDatabaseInstance.PublishTables(ISterlingDriver driver)
>          at Wintellect.Sterling.Database.SterlingDatabase.RegisterDatabase[T](ISterlingDriver driver)
>          at Waf.Dal.SterlingService.Starting()
>          at Waf.Dal.Factory.Sterling.InitializeDatabase()
>          at Waf.Dal.AireaStorageHelper.InitializeDatabase()
>          at Waf.App.App..ctor()
>     InnerException:

Update: I tried to replace the folder value

```
var folder = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\MyApp\\").Replace("\\","/");
```

And the exception goes away, but my original problem persists, it's like the 2 instances of the app are using different IsolatedStorages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I placed on the update, this fixed my problem with the isolated storage driver:

```
var folder = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\\MyApp\\").Replace("\\","/");
```

BUT, I learned that isolated storages are not shared between instances of the same application.

Hopes this is of use for someone